# logical consequence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

false:- a,b
false:- c
a:- p,r
a:- q
b.

Would the logical consequences be {b,~c,~p,~q, ~r}.

My reasoning is that for 'false:- a,b' to be true, either a or b (or both) has to be false, it has to be 'a' because 'b' is true. For 'a' to be false, 'q' has to be false and 'p' or 'r' has to be false. Please do correct me. What would be a good way to find the logical consequences given a set of clauses like these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're good until the part with $p$ and $r$.  All you can say about them is that they cannot both be true. But that does not mean that they are both false: one of them could be true and the other false. So, you cannot determine the truth value of either one.

So, as logical consequence you have $b$, $\neg a$, $\neg c$, $\neg q$, and $\neg (p \land r)$

Comment: what would be a good procedure for finding logical consequences for such definite clauses?